# fetch value for specific key from python dictionary using for loop and pass it onto another python script

Tags: python

here is my python code and i am trying to fetch specific value from python dictionary and pass it on to python script i wrote for cloning git file.

```
import git, shutil, os

nested_dictionary = {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "IT DEPART",
    "team": [

          {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "web",
        "package": [
          {
            "package_name": "codeDog_git",
            "package_url1": "https://github.com/mickymous1/CodeDog.git"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "codeDog_zip",
            "package_url": "https://github.com/mickymous1/CodeDog/archive/refs/heads/master.zip"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "3dchess_apt",
            "package_url": "apt-get install 3dchess"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "packageBDF",
            "package_url": ""
          },
          {
            "package_name": "packageXYZ",
            "package_url": "Package_url packageXYZ"
          }
        ]
      },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Mobile",
            "package": [
                {
                    "package_name": "tarball",
                    "package_url": "https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/tarball/master"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageZZZZZ"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "packageSADJKSA",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageSADJKSA"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "packageBDF",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageSADJKSA"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "packageXYZ",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageXYZ"
                }
            ]
    },
        ]
  }
```

This is my nested dictionary from which i am trying to fetch url for key  **"package_url1"** using python method mentioned below.

```
for p in [item for x in nested_dictionary['team'] for item in x['package']]:

   child = p.get('package_url1')
```

Here i am able to fetch value for **"package_url1"** but i am seeing printed value like this :-

```
scratches$ python scratch.py 

https://github.com/mickymous1/CodeDog.git
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

i just want url for specific key  but i am unable to get it, i want to get rid of **None** Response i am getting with url.

```
DIR_NAME = "temp"
REMOTE_URL = "https://github.com/hasinhayder/LightBulb.git"

if os.path.isdir(DIR_NAME):
    shutil.rmtree(DIR_NAME)

os.mkdir(DIR_NAME)

repo = git.Repo.init(DIR_NAME)
origin = repo.create_remote('origin', child)
origin.fetch()
origin.pull(origin.refs[0].remote_head)
```

and after getting url , i want to pass it on in python method mentioned above which create folder name temp and clone git repository to it.

But i just need url for specific key value i tried everything possible but i can not get rid of **None** response.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. Most of your dictionaries simply have no `package_url1` key (most of them have a `package_url` key with a value, but not a `package_url1` key)—only one of the dictionaries in your example has a `package_url1` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to `git` but you can simply iterate over your list and get rid of the `None` that comes from the `.get` operation:

```
my_urls = list(filter(None,[item.get("package_url1") for x in nested_dictionary['team'] for item in x['package']]))
```

or in your for loop you should check for the eventual `None` and not include it in your final list.

Or maybe you could use `nested_lookup` pip package that find for keys in nested dict